# Is a single Cookie Based API for multiple frontends possible from a CORS perspective?

Tags: angularjs, api, cookies, cross-domain

I originally wrote an REST API to work with a previously written mobile app. The mobile programmer requested from me to generate an `auth_token` on login that he will pass as a header on each request that needed authentication. This API runs at `api.example.com`.

Later on, I was commissioned to write an AngularJS app that communicates with this API, so I had to use `Access-Control-Allow` headers on the backend for OPTIONS requests to be CORS compatible [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) so my browser allows the connection (looks like iOS does not look for this headers). This app runs at `one.example.com`.

Now, I have to write a second AngularJS app that will run at `two.example.com` and there's a third being planned for the near future at `three.example.com`.

My problem is that my `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header looks like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://one.example.com:80
```

`*` is not allowed, nor I'm able to set this header to more than one origin. So as far as I can see I have two solutions:

1. Implement `token-based` authentication in parallel to the current `cookie-based` one. I'm thinking on [this](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/). This will of course take some time I'm willing to save.
2. Send the requester a header or param to the API endpoint identifying the app on the OPTIONS request and server-side, produce the CORS headers accordingly. I don't even know if it's possible and this looks nasty for even thinking it.

Any better ideas?

Comment: What language do you use for API?

Comment: @Yagiz PHP/Laravel. How is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same origin, example the same domain (example.com) or the same subdomain (1.ex.example.com and 2.ex.example.com) they can share the same cookie. Because cookie is based on the domain itself.

Comment: The browser is automatically issuing the OPTIONS request and looking for an origin set in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. An origin is represented by schema + domain + port. If these three are not the exact ones that I'm using, the request fails. Am I doing something wrong then?

Comment: No @Mauro, OPTIONS request is used to identify the different HTTP methods that Client can use. Therefore, you should change the CORS settings from API side. You should write *.example.com as your cookie domain origin.

Comment: that doesn't work: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/auth/login. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://*.example.com:9002' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://admin.example.com:9002' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: how is that relevant? That's just my local dev environment. I set the grunt server to that port so it doesn't conflict.